# Setting Default Font for PdfPCell with ItextPDF

Tags: java, fonts, itext, pdfptable

I have some working code that creates my PdfPTable cells but it seems a bit inefficient.

```
pList.add(i,new Paragraph());
Paragraph p=pList.get(i++);
p.setFont(headerFont);
p.add(new Chunk("Actual"));
p.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
p.add(new Chunk("Time"));
table.addCell(new PdfPCell(p));
.
.
.
```

This sequence of code is repeated for each cell but it seems like I should be able to at least set the font just once. I have searched for a way to set a default font for PdfPCells but came up with nothing. What method do I use to change the default font for PdfPCells?

Also I made the assumption that I need to keep every paragraph. Thus the use of an ArrayList.  Was that a correct assumption and must I keep every paragraph created or can I reuse the paragraph object after it is added to the table?

TIA.

Comment: Font inheritance was introduced in iText 7. Looking add your code, I'd say you're using iText 5 or earlier. You are right: iText 5 looks a bit inefficient. Then again: iText 5 is an old iText version. The latest version is much less inefficient.

Comment: OK, so there is nothing I can do. Yet another reason to upgrade before I get too far into this.